# Text-to-Speech in on View Pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, text-to-speech

- I have view pager, and few text in every page, i have a button ,on button press text-to-speech event is fire
- I know how to use text-to-speech, but when it comes to viewPager i dont know
- Code :

  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
          TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

  ```
  private TextToSpeech tts;
  private Button btnSpeak;
  private EditText txtText;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


      tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

      btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

      txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText);

      // button on click event
      btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {
              speakOut();
          }

      });
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
      // Don't forget to shutdown!
      if (tts != null) {
          tts.stop();
          tts.shutdown();
      }
      super.onDestroy();
  }

  @Override
  public void onInit(int status) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

          int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

          // tts.setPitch(5); // set pitch level

          // tts.setSpeechRate(2); // set speech speed rate

          if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                  || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
              Log.e("TTS", "Language is not supported");
          } else {
              btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
              speakOut();
          }

      } else {
          Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
      }

  }

  private void speakOut() {

      String text = txtText.getText().toString();

      tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
  }
  ```

  }

-- How to implement this in viewpager,and speak(convert) text that are particular in page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to make the `tts object` static in `MainActivity`

Then from your fragments you can call `MainActivity.tts.stop()` etc.

It would probably be better to include some helper methods in `MainActivity` such as:

```
public static TextToSpeech getTTS(){
return tts;
}
```

and to avoid null pointers:

```
public static boolean isTTSAvailable(){
return tts != null // && ttsInitialised
}
```

Where you would set a static boolean to true if `onInit` returned SUCCESS.

`MainActivity` would continue to handle releasing the `tts object` in `onDestroy` etc.

As a side note, it's always good practice to check out the [memory profiler in Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/performance/comparison.html) to make sure that holding a static reference to any object such as this has no adverse effects. Do before and after analysis and run the garbage collector manually etc to check you are holding no unwanted references after your Activity has been destroyed. This is very generic advice, but whenever making a code change such as this, it's good to know that there are no side-effects.